# How to make thread safe of a static variable in a web contronller

Tags: java, spring, servlets, thread-safety

As I know that as default the controller is singleton scope. If there is a static variable in a controller, how can I make it thread safe?

Except use synchronized way to take care of it, is there any other way?

Comment: Making a variable thread-safe doesn't mean much. We don't know the type of the variable, what it contains, if it's final or not, when it's initialized, what it is for, if and when it's mutated, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) to perform thread-safe read/write operations on some shared object:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class Something {
    private static SomeObject object = new SomeObject();
    private static ReadWriteLock objectLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void doSomething() {
        objectLock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            //reading something from object
        } finally {
            objectLock.readLock().unlock();
        }

        objectLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            //writing something in object
        } finally {
            objectLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in this example, if the value of the `object` variable ever changes (not the object itself), it should be declared with the `volatile` modifier.